# Issue with invalid use of incomplete type when using std::tuple_element

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple, stdhash

The following code implements a hash function for a `std::tuple` which is then used in a different segment of my code-base in a `std::unordered_map` of `std::tuple`s.

```
// compute hash function recursively through each std::tuple element
template<class Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct tuple_hash_compute {
    static std::size_t hash_compute(const Tuple& t) {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<N-1, decltype(t)>::type; // OFFENDING LINE
        return tuple_hash_compute<Tuple, N-1>::hash_compute(t)
            + std::hash<type>()(std::get<N-1>(t));
    }
};
// base helper
template<class Tuple>
struct tuple_hash_compute<Tuple, 1> {
    static std::size_t hash_compute(const Tuple& t) {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(t)>::type; // OFFENDING LINE
        return 51U + std::hash<type>()(std::get<0>(t))*51U;
    }
};
// tuple_hash function object
struct tuple_hash {
    template<class... Args>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::tuple<Args...>& t) const {
        return tuple_hash_compute<decltype(t), sizeof...(Args)>::hash_compute(t);
    } 
    // will use std::unordered_map of std::pair too, so overload reqd
    template<class Ty1, class Ty2>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<Ty1, Ty2>& p) const {
        return tuple_hash_compute<decltype(t), 2>::hash_compute(p);
    }
};
```

Then, just as an example, I would use this hash function-object like so,

```
std::unordered_map<std::tuple<int,int,int>, std::size_t, tuple_hash> agg_map;
agg_map.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(1,2,3), 0U));
agg_map.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(4,5,6), 1U));
```

However, in both `GCC 6.1.0` and `MSVC2015`, I receive the following errors (both the same for each offending line above):

> error: invalid use of incomplete type '`class std::tuple_element<2ul, const std::tuple<int,int,int>&>`'

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this error (though it may be due to "abstraction" of passing the `std::tuple` via the template parameter `Tuple`) or how it can be solved so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use `Tuple` instead of `decltype(t)` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'm afraid I tried that already and received the same error.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/655758eda525a016

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Hmmm, interesting, ok I got it working in `GCC` now (maybe I was missing a relevant `#include` somehow) but it still doesn't like it in `MSVC2015` - I get `use of undefined type std::tuple_element<2, Tuple>` as an error in this case.

Comment: you probably forgot to replace `decltype(t)` by `std::tuple<Args...>` (ditto `std::pair`), I don't know why it fails with msvc

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Ah, nevermind, I didn't realise you had replaced that line too - it works in both GCC and MSVC now, thanks :) Write it as an answer and I'll accept it (once I'm back from eating), though I'm curious as to why this change works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a parameter declared as below:

```
const Tuple& t
```

`decltype(t)` yields:

```
const Tuple&
```

Similarly, for a parameter declared as:

```
const std::pair<Ty1, Ty2>& t
```

`decltype(t)` yields:

```
const std::pair<Ty1, Ty2>&
```

In both cases, the produced type is a reference to a tuple-like type. However, [`std::tuple_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) is not specialized for references, which means, the compiler falls back to the primary, undefined class template:

```
template <size_t I, typename T> class tuple_element;
```

What you want, is a plain `Tuple` in the former case, and `std::pair<Ty1, Ty2>` in the latter case.

Comment: And if you have a case where you need to use `decltype` you can use `std::decay_t<decltype(t)>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem with a type `Tuple` that may or may not be a reference, you can use `std::remove_reference` like so:

```c++
typename std::tuple_element<num, typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::type
```

or, for C++17,

```c++
std::tuple_element_t<num, std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>
```

PS: I don't think it works with `std::reference_wrapper` though...